# connect method redux arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

The following piece of syntax when dealing with redux's `connect` method is confusing me.

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoItem)
```

`connect` takes two arguments, `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps`, which makes sense. The same as any function i.e.

```
function sum(a, b){
   return a + b;
}

sum(2, 8);
```

However, what is confusing me is the the next argument, in the example I provided above `(TodoItem)`. Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export a component from your JSX. The `connect` function is a *higher order function*, meaning it returns a new function.

The new function that it returns is actually a *higher order component*. This means that it is a component that returns another component. In this case, it is the `Provider` component that wraps your component.

At this point:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
```

you've not actually told the `connect` function which component to wrap.

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodoItem)
```

But here you've also told it which component to wrap.

**Summary**

So the first two functions you pass in as arguments tell it what the component needs. The last function argument tells it which component it is that needs them.

Answer (score 1):

This is function [currying](https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/).
In general, this is a function that returns a function.
In the connect the use case is to pass the component as an argument to the "second" inner function and that way it will have access for all 3 parameters.

One simple use case is when you want to pass extra parameter to `onClick` event.

```js
var root = document.getElementById('root');
root.addEventListener('click', clicked('i Was clicked!!'));

function clicked(param){
  return function(e){
    // both parameters acceesible
    console.log(param);
    console.log(e.target.innerHTML);    
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="root">Click me</button>
```

So behind the scene it invoked like this:

```
clicked('i was clicked!!')(event)
```